# Get SUM of a table column with 'for loop' in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to get the sum total of a 'table' column (getShotsTotal), 'forEach' worked fine in Ionic1 but fails in Ionic2, Any help would be appreciated. I think a standard 'Loop' may be required but as a newbie I am unsure of the correct method and code.

HTML:

```
<tr class="row header" *ngFor = "let par of Course; let i=index" >
<td class="col">{{i +1}}</td>
<td class="col1">{{par.Index}}</td>
<td class="col">{{par.Par}}</td>
<td class="col2">{{getPoints(par)}}</td>
<td class="col">{{getShots()}}</td>
<td class="col3" ><select [(ngModel)]="par.sel" 
(change)="onChangeScore(par.sel)"><option  *ngFor= "let s of items" >{{s}}
</option></select></td>
</tr>

<tr class="row" style="height:32px">
<td class="col">Total</td>
<td class="col"></td>
<td class="col"></td>
<td class="col"></td>
<td class="col">{{getTotalShots()}}</td>
<td class="col"></td>
</tr>
```

TS:

```
getShots(par) {
let val =  this.selectedHcp - par.Index;
if (val > 17.4) {
  return 2;
} else if (val >= -0.5) {
  return 1;
} else if (val < -0.5) {
  return 0;
}
};


getTotalShots = function () {
if (!this.Par) { return 0;
                 }
var total = 0;
angular.forEach(this.Par, function (item, index) {
total = total + (this.getShots(item) || 0);
});
return total;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop the array stored in `this.Par`, you can use `forEach` directly:

```
var total = 0;
this.Par.forEach((item, index) => {
    total += this.getShots(item) || 0
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, however I am getting the following error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: So the property this.Par is undefined, or it may be defined in another context. Can you show the component code?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking for: export class CardPage { Par : any; }

Comment: In template you are using ngFor on Course, shouldn't you use it instead of Par? Then you could iterate with `this.Course.forEach`

Comment: You guys are awesome!!      this.Course.forEach((item, index) => {
    total += this.getShots(item) || 0
});     Works like a dream!!  THANK YOU!